# Evaluating an integral with very small (but non-zero) numbers

Tags: python, numeric, integral

I wish to evaluate the following integral:
[image]

I tried to calculate the integral using python, with the following code:

```
def findint(k, x, g, n, q, s):
    f = lambda t, m: ((m*gamma(k)*gamma(t-k)*gamma(n)*gamma(t-n))/(gamma(m)*gamma(k-m)*gamma(n-m)*gamma(t-k-n+m)*gamma(t)*math.sqrt(2*math.pi)*x*s))*math.exp(-0.5*((t-x*q)/(x*s))**2)
    i=integrate.dblquad(f, 0, k, lambda m: n, lambda m: np.inf)
    return i

x = 80
g = 250
n = g*x
q = 300
s = 7
k=250

print(findint(k, x, g, n, q, s))
```

But when I try to run the code, I get the following error:

```
invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  f = lambda t, m: ((m*gamma(k)*gamma(t-k)*gamma(n)*gamma(t-n))/(gamma(m)*gamma(k-m)*gamma(n-m)*gamma(t-k-n+m)*gamma(t)*math.sqrt(2*math.pi)*x*s))*math.exp(-0.5*((t-x*q)/(x*s))**2)
(nan, 0)
```

It seems that the numbers in the denominator of the function are very small, and do so the system thinks I'm trying to divide by 0 (correct me if you think there is some other explanation of the error). How can I avoid this and calculate the integral?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide gamma function ?

Comment: It is the usual gamma function (extending factorial to the complex numbers) @azro

Comment: `from math import gamma` ? Because when i run the code I get `OverflowError: math range error`

Comment: from scipy.special import gamma

Comment: Might some of the arguments to gamma be negative, or are there constraints on K and n that ensure that doesn't happen?